# Excel way of transforming a Div/o into a 'NOT APPLICABLE'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to make a div/0 into a 'Not applicable'. The div/0 looks extremely unorganised and a 'N/A' would look a lot better. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make it really simple with something like..

```
=If(A2 = 0, "N/A", yourformula)
```

Answer (score 4):

Surround the formula you are using in `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(yourformula,"Not Applicable")
```

Comment: In fariness to @ScottCraner, he's following the spec exactly; I'm not.

Comment: @Jeeped I read it that the OP wanted `"Not Applicable"`, but yes if the OP wants `#N/A` error then replace `"Not Applicable"` with `NA()`

Answer (score 2):

The robust way is to check for the potential of a division by zero, and set the result to `NA()` in that case:

```
=IF(denominator = 0, NA(), numerator / denominator)
```

Else hack it with

```
=IFERROR(cell, NA())
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to check for the error would be something like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(ERROR.TYPE([your formula])),[your formula],IF(ERROR.TYPE([your formula])=2,[replacement for 'DIV/0!],[your formula]))
```

This way, only `#DIV/0!` will be replaced. If different errors pop up like `#REF!` or `#VALUE!`, they will still be shown. Just using `IFERROR` will replace ALL errors.

So if something else pops up (like `#REF!` because someone used *drag and drop* of a cell) you will see it directly.

However: you need to input the whole formula 4 times... :P